# gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: gst_aggregator_simple_get_next_time

Tags: gnome, gstreamer, gnome-control-center

A few days back I was trying to build **wxWidgets-3.15** library on **Ubuntu 21.04** with multiple flags enabled. I've had some issues with the build so I made a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087508/wxwidgets-sample-files-mediaplayer-ans-splash-dont-compile) on that on stackoverflow.

Unfortunately, not only I didn't manage to build the library after all, but it seems that in the process I messed up something regarding the **GStreamer** library. Specifically, the module `libgstvideo-1.0.so.0` of the package `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0` seems to be malfunctioning, and I can't open **gnome-control-center**, getting the following error:

```
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: gst_aggregator_simple_get_next_time
```

I've tried reinstalling, removing with `--purge`, autoremoving and upgrading `gnome-control-center`, `ubuntu-desktop`, `libgstreamer-1.0-0` and installing all suggested packages as well but nothing has worked so far. I've also had added previously some *NVidia* drivers as shown in another AskUbuntu post,because it is not the first time running into issue with `gnome-control-center`. I've also looked at all the other posts around this issue but no solution has worked so far. Does anyone know what I'm suppossed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally found it. **GStremer** had installed some libs under `/usr/local/lib`, specifically `libgstbase-1.0.so`, `libgstbase-1.0.so.0`, `libgstbase-1.0.so.0.1405.0`, `libgstreamer-1.0.la`, `libgstreamer-1.0.so`, `libgstreamer-1.0.so.0` and `libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.1405.0`. After I removed them `gnome-control-center` worked fine. I hope nothing else has broken, I'll edit if I find something else out.